# using minus sign in zend routes

Tags: zend-framework, routes

Is it possible to use minus sign within url so that zend route can handle it ?

Currently, i have in my application config :

```
resources.router.routes.post.route = "1-:id-:title"
resources.router.routes.post.defaults.controller = category
resources.router.routes.post.defaults.action = index
```

but zend route is not able to resolve that request_uri : **/1-1-T_Shirt__Chemise**

However if i put

```
resources.router.routes.post.route = "1/:id/:title"
```

zend route is nicely resolving that request_uri : **/1/1/T_Shirt__Chemise**

Any ideas ?

Comment: thanks for the tip. Posting this as a comment proves that you're aware that's not an acceptable answer :)

Comment: It was posted only partly in jest. Seriously, if you've found something that works, then why not use it? Or is there some other factor you haven't stated in your post?

Comment: You're right. I would use it, but SEO-artistically, that does not fit, and more rationnally, i would think the slashes bear a semantical different meaning. I manage to achieve what i wanted using regexp, but that's too heavy, so i would like a lighter solution